# PHP to JQuery: json_encode not working

Tags: php, jquery, getjson, json

I have been struggling to figure this out of the past couple days.  In fact, as I am new to all of this it seems I am constantly trying to figure something out.  Anyway, on to my question.

I am trying to encode an array in PHP and retrieve it in JQuery using JSON using the following code:

Included function from 'core/init.php':

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    echo json_encode($errors);
}
```

login.php:

```
<?php

include 'core/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a username and password.';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username.  Have you registered?';
} else if (user_active($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account.';
} else {
    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect.';
    } 
    else {
    //start session
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
    //redirect to home.
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
} else {
header('Location: index.php');
}

include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (empty($errors) === false) {

?>

<h2>We tried to log you in but...</h2>

<?php

output_errors($errors);

}

include 'includes/overall/footer.php';

?>
```

JQuery:

```
function logErrors(errors) {
    alert(errors);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('login.php', function(errors){
    logErrors(errors);
    });
});
```

I am working locally and have gotten it to work a test file:

test.php:

```
<?php

function output_errors($errors) {
echo json_encode($errors);
}

output_errors($errors);

?>
```

In some of my research I have found that the version of PHP may be an issue.  That doesn't seem to be my problem as I have gotten it to work with another file.

Another common problem others seem to have is the fact that $.getJSON is asynchronous and may be running before php has a chance to return the array.  I'm not sure if my JQuery is structured properly or not to avoid that issue.

What I keep getting is no alert and the error echoed like this: ["We can't find that username. Have you registered?"].

How do I get my JQuery to retrieve the encoded array and trigger the function logErrors?

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer. Sorry if I posted too much code or not enough...rookie mistake.

UPDATE

Here are the user_exists and user_active functions:

user_exists:

```
function user_exists($username) {
   $username = sanitize($username);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` =    '$username'");
   return (mysql_result($query,0) == 1) ? true : false;     
}
```

user_active:

```
function user_active($username) {
   $username = sanitize($username);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'AND `active` = 1");
   return (mysql_result($query,0) == 1) ? true : false;     
}
```

E

Comment: Might need to do print_r() instead of echo; might need to have a header with content-type explicitly set to a javascript object.  I can't tell which piece of code is index.php.  Could you label them better?

Comment: I ran it with print_r($errors) and got this: Array ( [0] => We can't find that username. Have you registered? ), in place of ["We can't find that username. Have you registered?"].  index.php isn't up there the php is from a login page I will try to update the labels to make it clearer.  Also, adding the header doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to alert an entire HTML page?  `$.getJSON('login.php', function(errors){ logErrors(errors); });` ought to alert the entire page.

Comment: where are the user_exists and user_active functions?

Comment: Think about what you're doing. You're asking jQuery to fetch *JSON*, but your PHP script outputs *JSON surrounded by HTML*. Do you expect jQuery to automagically figure out where JSON starts and ends?

Comment: Bozdoz - I'm not trying to alert an entire page, I just want to trigger an alert containing the errors.  When I run the function with test.php I get an alert.  It's blank, but at least the function is triggered.  I'm not certain but I thought the function is trigger upon a successful retrieval of data.  Dcoder: I'm not sure exactly what you mean here.  $errors is an empty array included in init/core.php.  So I figured output_errors would only send the input ($errors) as JSON.  Does breaking in and out of php within a function compromise that?

Comment: Bozdoz: I updated the question with the functions you wanted to see.  Bozdoz and Dcoder thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out.  bozdoz and DCoder turned out to be right.  I did not realize that php would echo the entire page (rookie mistake).  I was under the impression that it would only echo the json_encoded array.

For anyone running into a similar issue, make sure you are working with a file that only echos the desired result.

Thanks for the help guys and gals.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be needing to set the header before returning the json object

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($errors);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working.  I gave it a shot earlier as I also came across that in my search for a solution.  I"m not sure if this helps either but  the test file doesn't seem to need it to work.